# Sum the values of the arrays for same keys

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to sum the values of an array based on key. right now i have come up with the following function. unfortunately at the end its throwing me Notice: Undefined offset
how can i avoid this notice ? other than that it works correctly.

```
$array1 = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3');
$array2 = array('2' => '10', '3' => '10', '4' => '10');
//$array3 = array('3' => '1', '4' => '2', '5' => '3');
$array = array_sum_values($array1, $array2);
print_r($array);

/**
 * Sums the values of the arrays be there keys (PHP 4, PHP 5) 
 * array array_sum_values ( array array1 [, array array2 [, array ...]] )
 */
function array_sum_values() {
    $return = array();
    $intArgs = func_num_args();
    $arrArgs = func_get_args();
    if ($intArgs < 1)
        trigger_error('Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_sum_values()', E_USER_WARNING);

    foreach ($arrArgs as $arrItem) {
        if (!is_array($arrItem))
            trigger_error('Warning: Wrong parameter values for array_sum_values()', E_USER_WARNING);
        foreach ($arrItem as $k => $v) {
            $return[$k] += $v;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

the output of above is,

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\TestPHP\index.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in E:\xampp\htdocs\TestPHP\index.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in E:\xampp\htdocs\TestPHP\index.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in E:\xampp\htdocs\TestPHP\index.php on line 24
Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 10 )
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [array_sum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) ?

Comment: @DainisAbols He would if he knew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of line

```
$return[$k] += $v
```

for each index first time this is called `$return[$k]` if undefined. 
It's perfectly ok to use silencer here:

```
@$return[$k] += $v.
```

Or, you can check each time if array index is defined (will probably slow function a bit). Add this line before `$return[$k] += $v;`:

```
if (!isset($return[$k])) $return[$k] = 0;
```

Comment: It was done by TS already. Undefined is INDEX, not the array itself. @DainisAbols

Comment: @DainisAbols i have already defined this in the start. please check my question and the code.

Comment: It's a better answer with the `isset()`, I would say it's bad to suggest it's OK to use Error Suppressor here.